# linkedin canot create sponsored Share

Tags: linkedin-api

when i used "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares" to create a Share for sponsored share,and got a Share id.
I post 
`{
    \"campaign\": \"urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:{$campaign_id}\",
    \"reference\": \"urn:li:share:{$share_id}\",
    \"status\": \"ACTIVE\",
    \"type\": \"SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE\",
    \"variables\": {
        \"data\": {
            \"com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables\": {}
        }
    }
}`  to create sponsored .but it return :

```
{"message":"Validation failed because [{reason=INVALID_VALUE_FOR_FIELD, field=reference, batchIndex=0, type=INVALID_VALUE, message=/reference cannot be set to urn:li:share:6316476667095322625, parameters={field=/reference, value=urn:li:share:6316476667095322625, key=}}]","status":400}
```

but ,for waiting few second,I used the same content create again ,I work and return me the "X-LinkedIn-Id".

I've compared two things, it's the same .
does it has something limited in create sponsored share?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ,when create a share ,It must wait for 30 second at least .and then ,you will create sponsored share success!